# Add javascript file to a block pattern

Tags: block-editor

I'm just thinking to make a sticky header for the twenty twenty-two theme and I was imagining to make it as a block pattern. Is this in your opinion a good approach?
If this is the right way to do it, how can I enqueue the javascript file to the block pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Your question actually is an open-ended/opinion-based question.  Recommend that you start here:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: you would need a custom block for this, it couldn't be done with only a pattern

Comment: Maybe I found another, cleaner, way.
Maybe I will add an option to the Header block called "Sticky header".
Then I will enqueue the javascript if that option is enabled.
What do you think about this way? Thanks!

Comment: @jdm2112 I was asking on which hook enqueue the javascript if that block pattern is enabled, I don't think that's a open-endend/opinion-based question.

Comment: "Is this in your opinion a good approach?" is the piece that potentially creates an open-ended discussion.